# Is there a way to get SmartSheet Forms using the REST API?

Tags: smartsheet-api

Using the [SmartSheet REST API](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io), is there any way to get the Forms associated with a Sheet (and their - the forms' - definition/metadata, such as questions, etc.)? There doesn't appear to be anything in the documentation, but I didn't know if I'm just missing it, or if it's perhaps called something else.

Answer (score 1):

You're not missing anything. At this time, accessing form data through the Smartsheet API is not supported.

Answer (score -1):

They said back in 2019 that it is in the nearby pipeline.  Considering its mid 2021, I feel as though it has gotten lost somewhere in this pipe.

Comment: Please consider using comments if your post isn't answering the question.